# HTML Hyperlink output into table

Tags: html, hyperlink, html-table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }

            .table td {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                padding: 10px 20px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 2px;
            }

            .table th {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: normal;
                padding: 10px 20px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 2px;
            }

            .table .tg-1 {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .table .tg-2 {
                font-weight: bold;
                background-color: #c0c0c0;
                text-align: center;
            }
    </style>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th class="tg-2">Animal Name</th>
            <th class="tg-2">Picture</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-1"><a href="Images/cat.jpg">Cat</a></td>
            <td rowspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <td class="tg-1"><a href="Images/Dog.jpg">Dog</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-1"><a href="Images/Horse.jpg">Horse</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<br>
```

I have created the above table with hyperlinks, the hyperlinks are opening in the same window/tab however I would like to open them in the blank column of my table.

Can you please offer some help?
How do I set the target of the hyperlink to the second column of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just HTML (and CSS) without client-side scripting, you would need to put an `iframe` element into the second column and make the links open in that `iframe`. (With scripting, you could alternatively just change the `src` attribute of an `img` element placed in the second column.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }

            .table td {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                padding: 10px 20px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 2px;
            }

            .table th {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: normal;
                padding: 10px 20px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 2px;
            }

            .table .tg-1 {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .table .tg-2 {
                font-weight: bold;
                background-color: #c0c0c0;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .table iframe {
                padding: 0;
                width: 216px;  /* modify as needed according to image size */
                height: 116px; /* use +16px in both to allow for internal padding */
                border: none;
            }
    </style>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th class="tg-2">Animal Name</th>
            <th class="tg-2">Picture</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-1"><a href="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/animals/" target="pic">Cat</a></td>
            <td rowspan="3"><iframe src="about:blank" name="pic"></iframe></td>
        </tr>
        <td class="tg-1"><a href="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/animals/" target="pic">Dog</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-1"><a href="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/animals/" target="pic">Horse</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that what you really need it for the hyperlinks to be replaced with image tags, e.g.:

```
<td class="tg-1"><image src="Images/Horse.jpg" alt="Horse"/></td>
```